# TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError() - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

Tags: spring, spring-scheduled

I got an error *TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError() - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task* with the following task by using Spring @Scheduled (version 5.3.14)

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "${delete.tmpdir.cron.expression}")
public void deleteTempFiles() {
    LOGGER.info("==> cron(deleteTempFiles) is executing time={}", new Date());
    
    LOGGER.debug("test1");
    LOGGER.debug("java.io.tmpdir: {}", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    LOGGER.debug("test2");
    File tmpFolder = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
    if (tmpFolder != null && tmpFolder.exists()) {
        LOGGER.debug("tmpFolder: {}, isFile:{},  isDirectory:{}", tmpFolder, tmpFolder.isFile(), tmpFolder.isDirectory());
    } else {
        LOGGER.warn("tmpFolder is null or not exists");
    }

    try {
        LOGGER.debug("listFiles a");
        File[] list = tmpFolder.listFiles(new XYZFileFilter());
        LOGGER.debug("listFiles b");

        if (list != null) {
            for (File file : list) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    LOGGER.debug("deleteTempFiles1 {}", file.getAbsolutePath());
                    boolean ret = file.delete();
                    LOGGER.debug("deleteTempFiles2 {} : {}", file.getAbsolutePath(), ret);
                }
            }
        }

        LOGGER.debug("listFiles z");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn("Exception: {}", e.getMessage());
    }

    LOGGER.info("<== cron(deleteTempFiles) is executing time={}", new Date());
}
    /**
 * File "xyz_*" > 1d
 * */
class XYZFileFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XYZFileFilter.class);
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        LOGGER.debug("accept {}", name);
        try {
            if (name !=null && name.startsWith("xyz_")) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                File file = new File(dir, name);
                if (file.isFile() && calendar.getTimeInMillis() > file.lastModified()) { // file >= 1d
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

logs

```
[INFO ] 2022-01-10 23:40:00,008 TestCronImpl.deleteTempFiles() - ==> cron(deleteTempFiles) is executing time=2022-01-10T23:40:00.008+0100
[DEBUG] 2022-01-10 23:40:00,008 TestCronImpl.deleteTempFiles() - test1
[DEBUG] 2022-01-10 23:40:00,008 TestCronImpl.deleteTempFiles() - java.io.tmpdir: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\
[DEBUG] 2022-01-10 23:40:00,009 TestCronImpl.deleteTempFiles() - test2
[DEBUG] 2022-01-10 23:40:00,009 TestCronImpl.deleteTempFiles() - tmpFolder: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp, isFile:false,  isDirectory:true
[DEBUG] 2022-01-10 23:40:00,009 TestCronImpl.deleteTempFiles() - listFiles a
[ERROR] 2022-01-10 23:40:00,010 TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler.handleError() - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
```

when i comment 'try catch' bloc, this task is termined correctly ...

i don't why? and how can i fix it?

thanks